# How come excel vba code not working on open?

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that is supposed to run on open, but I don't understand why it's not working.  If I step through the code I will work just fine.  And I can run it manually just fine, but the code never works on open.

I have the code in ThisWorkbook, and I've searched for other threads but I can't find a fix.  Any idea what's going on?

```
 Private Sub RefreshAndClose_Open()

    If DateDiff("h", "12", Hour(Now)) <= 0 And DateDiff("n", "50", Minute(Now)) <= 50 Then
        ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
        DoEvents
        ThisWorkbook.Save
        DoEvents
        Application.Quit
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You can't change the handler for the [`Workbook_Open`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.open) event.

Comment: The event is `Workbook_Open()`, don't mess with it!

Comment: If you want to run this, then you need to either change the sub signature to `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` or add the `Workbook_Open` handler and within it `Call RefreshAndClose_Open()`.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks I wasn't aware of that, obvious beginner here.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you're Excel.

You have a `Workbook` opened, and a `Worksheet` is active. Now the user clicks somewhere and the `Selection` changes. Lots of low-level boilerplate non-VBA code needs to run for this to happen, but at one point or another, this happens (pseudo-code) somewhere in the `Worksheet` object's guts:

```
RaiseEvent SelectionChange(ActiveCell)
```

This raises the `Worksheet.SelectionChange` event:

[image: Members of 'Worksheet', with 'SelectionChange' event selected (as seen in the Object Browser)]

When this event is raised, if there's a *handler* for this event, that's when it will be invoked. This handler needs to be wired up - you can do that yourself using a `WithEvents` object variable, but Excel's *document modules* make it very easy to wire up a handler - simply go to the `Worksheet` module you want to handle worksheet events for, select `Worksheet` from the code pane's left-side dropdown...

[image: code pane dropdowns, left one is dropped, 'Worksheet' is selected]

...and the VBE creates the handler procedure for you - note the contents of the two dropdowns:

[image: Worksheet::SelectionChange handler signature was added automatically by the editor]

The handler procedure is named in a very specific way:

```
LeftSideDropdownValue_RightSideDropdownValue
```

The "left-side dropdown value" is the *interface* you want to implement a member for; the "right-side dropdown value" is the specific member you're implementing.

If you placed the caret inside your procedure, the left-side dropdown would say `(General)` - that means it's just another procedure, and if nothing is invoking it then it's just another *unused* procedure that might as well not exist.

So, you're the Excel application, and you're opening a workbook. The exact same thing happens: lots of low-level boilerplate non-VBA code needs to run as a bunch of objects are being deserialized from the .xlsm macro-enabled workbook file loaded from disk, and when everything is good to go this happens (pseudo-code) somewhere in the opened `Workbook` object's guts:

```
RaiseEvent Open
```

This raises the `Workbook.Open` event:

[image: Members of 'Workbook', with 'Open' event selected (as seen in the Object Browser)]

Once again, we could declare a `WithEvents` object variable and wire-up a handler ourselves, but a VBA project hosted in Excel will always have a `Workbook` document module that already does this for us - so in order to handle the `Workbook.Open` event, we can go to the `ThisWorkbook` module, select `Workbook` from the left-side dropdown, and have the VBE automatically generate a well-formed handler for us:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

End Sub
```

Again, the reason VBA knows this procedure is handling the `Workbook.Open` event, is because the name says so:

```
[Interface]_[Member]
```

If we go and change the name to anything else, we break that link, and we know the link is broken because the left-side code pane dropdown will be saying `(General)` and not `Workbook`.

This special naming scheme is also the reason why you should avoid using underscores in your own procedure names: they make procedures *look* like event handlers, but they're not. In certain specific advanced scenarios, using underscores in member names can even cause compile errors. Best take the good habit early on, of sticking to simple `PascalCase` for procedure names.

If we go and change the list of parameters in any way that makes it incompatible with the event's declaration, we get a compile error:

[image: Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name]

You can safely tweak the parameter names (although, I can't think of any good reason to do this), but the parameter data types and their ordering cannot be modified.

See [everything you ever wanted to know about events](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2019/03/27/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-events/) for more info (I wrote that article).