# Passing an array between click Subs in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to declare and populate an array variable (coll), but wish to access the contents of the array in another Sub (UnassignButton_Click()). I keep getting the error:

> Compile error: Sub or Function not defined

Below is my code:

```
Public Sub SearchButton_Click()
Dim RowNum As Long
Dim SearchRow As Long
Dim coll As Object
Set coll = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

RowNum = 2
SearchRow = 2

Do Until Cells(RowNum, 1).Value = ""
    If InStr(1, Cells(RowNum, 1).Value, SearchTextBox.Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Worksheets("Search_Results").Cells(SearchRow, 1).Value = Cells(RowNum, 1).Value
        Worksheets("Search_Results").Cells(SearchRow, 2).Value = Cells(RowNum, 2).Value
        Worksheets("Search_Results").Cells(SearchRow, 3).Value = Cells(RowNum, 3).Value
        Worksheets("Search_Results").Cells(SearchRow, 4).Value = Cells(RowNum, 4).Value
        Worksheets("Search_Results").Cells(SearchRow, 5).Value = Cells(RowNum, 5).Value
        Worksheets("Search_Results").Cells(SearchRow, 6).Value = Cells(RowNum, 6).Value
        Worksheets("Search_Results").Cells(SearchRow, 7).Value = Cells(RowNum, 7).Value
        Worksheets("Search_Results").Cells(SearchRow, 8).Value = Cells(RowNum, 8).Value
        Worksheets("Search_Results").Cells(SearchRow, 9).Value = Cells(RowNum, 9).Value
        SearchRow = SearchRow + 1
        coll.Add RowNum
    End If
    RowNum = RowNum + 1
Loop

If SearchRow = 2 Then
    MsgBox "No products were found that match your search criteria"
    Exit Sub
End If

SearchResultsListBox.RowSource = "SearchResults"

End Sub

Private Sub SearchResultsListBox_Click()
NumberIndex = SearchResultsListBox.ListIndex
End Sub

Public Sub UnassignButton_Click()
NumberIndex = SearchResultsListBox.ListIndex
MsgBox coll(NumberIndex)

End Sub
```

Any help to resolve this issue would be much appreciated!

Comment: It's all a matter of `scope`.  The `coll` object is defined in your sub and only visible in that sub.  You need to move it to the top of your file making it global.

Comment: @BrianMStafford \*making it *instance state* (assuming we're looking at a UserForm or Worksheet module), not global ;-)

Answer (score 2):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58086375/1188513) for why you can't just willy-nilly tweak event handler procedure signatures to suit your needs.

Each procedure defines a *scope*. Local variables (whether declared with `Dim`, ...or not declared at all) live inside that procedure scope, and have no way out.

The next higher-up scope level is *module scope*. Variables declared in that scope are accessible to all procedures in the module. Use the `Private` keyword to declare them (`Dim` is also legal, but I prefer to reserve it for locals, since `Private` isn't legal at procedure level) - consider using a *meaningful* identifier name, too... "coll" doesn't say much about *what it's for*:

```
Option Explicit
Private RowNumbers As Object
```

And then you can initialize it in the `Initialize` handler:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set RowNumbers = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
End Sub
```

Probably also a good idea to explicitly wipe it out in the `Terminate` handler too, since that's a .NET object (FWIW this isn't a VBA array at all and has nothing to do with arrays):

```
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    Set RowNumbers = Nothing
End Sub
```

The next higher-up scope level is *global scope*, but once you understand how to pass parameters between procedures, and when to use module scope variables, you pretty much never need any globals. For completleness' sake, a global variable would be declared in a *standard module*, using the `Public` keyword (`Global` works too, but makes things confusing since what we call "global" is really just "project-scope", and besides `Public` is much more clearly antagonizing `Private`, so it's good for consistency).

---

If you added `Option Explicit` to the top of your modules, VBA would refuse to compile code that uses undeclared variables - and that would have highlighted `coll` and, likely, `NumberIndex` as well.

See if [Rubberduck](http://www.rubberduckvba.com/) inspections flag other issues (disclaimer: I manage that open-source project).